# Event triggers method but doesn't update the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, updatepanel, postback

So I have many listboxes in an update panel. The first one's OnselectedIndexChanged event triggers a method that updates the next one and so on. Right now only the first listbox correctly updates the second. The second doesn't update the 3rd like it should.

And when in debug. I click on the 2nd ListBox (ModelList)  it triggers the event correctly according to the debugger. The values in the C# codebehind are being updated, but changes are not displayed on the webpage like they are in the first.

There is a label for example where I can see  its text property change in debug. But its not changing the website.
 The other interesting thing is, once the second listbox is clicked the first one stops updating but the codebehind methods still fire without exception :-/

Okay enough talk. Here is my code. (The relevant parts).

ASP.NET CODE

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server"> 

        <%--register triggers for Partial postback --%>
          <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="showbutton" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="viewapps" EventName="Click" />

          </Triggers>

          <ContentTemplate>
      <%--- the controls in their rows and columns --%>

            <%--column 1 --%>

     <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="column1">

         <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="row1">

             <%-- Make Panel --%>
                               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="TESTER">Text</asp:Label>
                            <span runat="server" style="padding:8px; position:relative;" >
                                <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="Make" Font-Size="Large" ></asp:Label>    
                                <asp:Listbox AutoPostback="true" ID="MakeList" runat="server" Width="166px" SelectionMode ="Multiple" DataTextField="MakeName" DataValueField="MakeID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UpdateModels" DataSourceID="MakeSource">
                                </asp:Listbox>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="MakeSource" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VCDBConnectionString %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                           </span>


         </asp:Panel>

         <%--Model Panel --%>
          <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass="row2" runat="server">
              <span runat="server" style="padding:8px; position:relative;">
                    <asp:Label ID="label8" runat="server" Text="Model" Font-Size="Large" ></asp:Label>    
                    <asp:Listbox  ID="ModelList" runat="server" Width="166px" SelectionMode="Multiple" DataSourceID="ModelSource" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UpdateYear" AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:Listbox>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ModelSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VCDBConnectionString %>" > </asp:SqlDataSource>
             </span>
         </asp:Panel>

    </asp:Panel> <%--End of Column1 --%>


            <%-- column 3--%>
    <asp:Panel CssClass="column3" runat="server">

        <%--Year Panel --%>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel7" CssClass="row1" runat="server">
           <span runat="server" style="padding:8px; position:relative;">
                <asp:Label ID="label13" runat="server" Text="Year" Font-Size="Large" ></asp:Label>    
                <asp:Listbox AutoPostback="true" ID="YearList" runat="server" Width="166px" SelectionMode="Multiple" DataSourceID="YearSource">
                </asp:Listbox>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="YearSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VCDBConnectionString %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
           </span>
        </asp:Panel>

        <%--End of Content Template! --%>
        <%--Don't put any Dynmaic content past here! --%>

    </ContentTemplate>

 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the C# codebehind.

```
  public partial class MassUpdate : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    //setup connection strings
  //  string VCDBconnect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VCDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
   // string ACESconnect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACESConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


    //utility lists for building complex queries
    List<string> selectedMakes= new List<string>();
    List<string> selectedModels = new List<string>();
    List<string> selectedYears = new List<string>();
    List<string> selectedSubmodels = new List<string>();
    List<string> selectedEngines = new List<string>();
    List<string> selectedLocations = new List<string>();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.IsPostBack == false) {


                  MakeSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT [MakeID], [MakeName] FROM [Make] ORDER BY [MakeName]";


            //setup the EVENTS
          //  MakeList.SelectedIndexChanged += UpdateModels;



        }//end of postback==false


    }//end of Page Load



  // called by selected index changed on Make
    public void UpdateModels(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //build a string for a SQL query for the Models
        string baseQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT M.[ModelID], M.[ModelName] FROM Model M INNER JOIN BaseVehicle BV ON BV.ModelID = M.ModelID Where BV.MakeID= '";
        string newQuery = "";

        selectedMakes.Clear();
        //build a query into a list which will be compiled later into a single string
        List<string> queryBuilder = new List<string>();

        //add the base query
        queryBuilder.Add(baseQuery);

        //add the seleted items to items in the list
            foreach (ListItem li in MakeList.Items)
            {

                if (li.Selected)
                {
                    queryBuilder.Add(li.Value);                 
                    queryBuilder.Add("' OR BV.MakeID = '");


                    //build the list of selected makes for later use
                    selectedMakes.Add(li.Value);
                }
            }
                try
                {
                    //remove the last  ' AND BV.MakeID= '
                    queryBuilder.RemoveAt(queryBuilder.Count-1);

                   //add back the ' and the orderby
                    queryBuilder.Add("'");
                    queryBuilder.Add(" ORDER BY [ModelName]");

                    //build the string
                    foreach(string s in queryBuilder){

                        newQuery+= s;

                    }


                    //debug for visibilty 
                    TESTER.Text =newQuery;

                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException) { TESTER.Text = "Argument Null"; }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { TESTER.Text = "Index out of range"; }
                catch (UpdateException) { TESTER.Text = "Update Problems"; }
                catch (Exception) { TESTER.Text = "Other Problems"; }


                ModelSource.SelectCommand = newQuery;
                ModelList.DataTextField="ModelName";
                ModelList.DataValueField = "ModelID";
            //    GroupList.Enabled = false;
            //    YearList.Enabled = false;



        }

    //called by onSelectedIndexchanged event from Model
    public void UpdateYear(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TESTER.Visible = false;
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
        try
        {


                //empty it so it doesn't reuse old selections in future queries.
                selectedModels.Clear();

                //build a string for a SQL query for the Models
                //basic idea = SELECT [YearID] FROM [BaseVehicle] Where [YearID] >='1950' AND ([MakeID] = ''  ) AND ([ModelID] = '') ORDER BY [YearID]
                string baseQuery = "SELECT [YearID] FROM [BaseVehicle] Where [YearID] >='1950' AND (";
                string addOn = " ORDER BY [YearID]";
                string newQuery = "";


                //build a query into a list which will be compiled later into a single string
                List<string> queryBuilder = new List<string>();

                //add the base query
                queryBuilder.Add(baseQuery);

                //will need a for each loop for each  where clause group
                //will need one for each loop for buiilding the selected list for model
                //will need a final foreach loop to build the query


                //add the seleted items from the make list
                queryBuilder.Add("[MakeID] ='");
                foreach (string li in selectedMakes)
                {



                    queryBuilder.Add(li);
                    queryBuilder.Add("' OR [MakeID] = '");


                }


                //<----    cleanup area  ---->

                //remove the last  ' OR MakeID= '
                queryBuilder.RemoveAt(queryBuilder.Count - 1);

                //add the ' to close the last ID value
                queryBuilder.Add("'");


                //close the where clause group with a ) 
                queryBuilder.Add(") ");

                //<---- END   cleanup area  ---->

                //start the new where clause group
                queryBuilder.Add("AND ([ModelID ='");

                foreach (ListItem li in ModelList.Items)
                {


                    if (li.Selected == true)
                    {


                        //add the selected item's ID to the queryBuilder as a string
                        queryBuilder.Add(li.Value);
                        queryBuilder.Add("' OR [ModelID] = '");


                        //build selected model list for later use
                        selectedModels.Add(li.Value);

                    }


                }

                //<----    cleanup area  ---->

                //remove the last  ' OR ModelID = '
                queryBuilder.RemoveAt(queryBuilder.Count - 1);

                //add the ' to close the last ID value
                queryBuilder.Add("'");


                //close the where clause group with a ) 
                queryBuilder.Add(") ");

                //<---- END   cleanup area  ---->


                //add the addons(ending clauses such as ORDER BY)
                queryBuilder.Add(addOn);


                //Build the query!!!




                //build the string
                foreach (string s in queryBuilder)
                {
                    /*somehow there are 2 select statements that are built right here */
                    newQuery += s;

                }

                try
                {
                    //debug for visibilty 
                    TESTER.Text = newQuery;



                    YearSource.SelectCommand = newQuery;
                    YearList.DataTextField = "YearID";
                    YearList.DataValueField = "YearID";
                }

                catch(Exception k)
                {
                    TESTER.Text = "SQL small block fail " +k.ToString();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception j) {

                TESTER.Text = j.ToString();
        }
             //UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }//end of method
```

So again, both methods work according to Debug, but only UpdateModels actually affects the webpage. And I have no idea why.

If it helps I first made this project in Visual Studio Express for Web 2010, then switched to Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web. There was an update/conversion process for my project. If that has anything to do with it, let me know.

Also, I am willing to post any additional source code upon request. If you think the contents of web.config are relevant for example. I will gladly post it.

Comment: When I go back to work Tomorrow(Monday for me) I will try setting the ChildrenAsTriggers property to be true.

Comment: Well, That did not work. Is this possibly a framework bug? Is there some max number of children an update panel can have?

Answer (score 0):

Your UpdatePanel1.Update() is commented out at the bottom of your UpdateYear function -- have you tried uncommenting it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `OnSelectedIndexChanged` on `YearList`.

Comment: Yearlist is getting populated by UpdateYear() which is called by ModelList's   OnSelectedIndexChanged="UpdateYear". You are correct though, YearList is missing an onSelectedIndexChanged. But setting it to a method doesn't fix the problem, I have tested that =\

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but `UpdatePanel1.Update();` should be last line of your `UpdateYear` function. you know why, Don't you?

Comment: You may find it worth your time to read the previous answers before responding. I already talked about this with Cortright.

Comment: If you scroll to the top of the UpdateYear function you see a part where I set TESTER's visible property to false  and then did UpdatePanel1.Update();    . The problem is TESTER is still visible on the webpage even after calling  the UpdatePanel's Update() method. Which is why I am stumped and came to StackOverFlow for help.